# How to fix ERROR: (26) file is not a database in Sqlite DB

Tags: sqlite

Cannot access to sqlite3 db by command line or application.
When I want to create an backup got this error

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\site\_private\lib>sqlite3 db.sdb ".dump"
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
/**** ERROR: (26) file is not a database *****/
ROLLBACK; -- due to errors
```

Btw when use some payed tools to recover  the db they found all the table and indexes, but we have to paye to continue the recovery.

other example when I want to list all the tables

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\site\_private\lib>sqlite3 db.sdb ".dump"
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
/**** ERROR: (26) file is not a database *****/
ROLLBACK; -- due to errors
```

Is there a solution to fix this issue.

Thank's

Comment: The error is likely correct, your db.sdb file is not an sqlite database file.

Comment: Is this sdb file perhaps already a dump of a database and thus just a bunch of SQL statements?

Comment: https://filext.com/file-extension/SDB
It's  an sqlite database file

Comment: I can give an executable a .txt extension but that doesn't make it a text file... It'd be nice if windows had the unix `file` program, which does a great job of guessing file formats.

Comment: @imtah Or it could be an openoffice database http://dotwhat.net/file/extension/sdb/10786 , or any of these https://pc.net/extensions/file/sdb